# Access IOwinRequest in Self Hosted Web API Outside of a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-host-webapi

I have a self hosted web api.  I have a log builder helper that populates a LogMessage object with a lot of details from the IOwinRequest object (i.e. requested url, ip address, http method, etc). I use this log helper to populate all of these details whenever the code logs a message.

For example within a service I have have code like this:

```
Logger.Debug(_logMessageCreator.CreateDebugMessage("Entered XYZ method"));
```

How can I access the IOwinRequest object from within the LogMessageCreator object?

This is happening outside of a Controller.